# css !important is not overriding in media query

Tags: css

Media query for ipad pro is not working because i am using two !important in css.

```css
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 1366px) and (max-device-height: 1024px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)  and (orientation: landscape)  {
svg#specilid {
    width: 230px !important;
    margin-left: -25px !important;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
}
}
```

```css
svg#specilid {
    width: 230px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
}
```

If normal desktop, i want to set margin-left as "0". If it is ipad pro, margin-left is "-25px".

I am using !important for both normal and media query.

I want !important in both places.

If I go for ipad pro version still the normal css ( "margin-left : 0px !important" ) only is there. It is not overriding.

Comment: Are you sure if this media query is getting picked up at the resolution you have?

Comment: Do you have them in the right order …? Provide a _proper_ [mre] in cases like this.

Comment: The media query should be after the regular code. Otherwise the normal code will override the query. Also using !important everywhere is bad practice.

Comment: your use of `!important` is causing more issues than it's worth. You should look into CSS-specicifity to have more robust styling.

Answer (score 1):

first add css without media query and then add media query below

```
svg#specilid {
    width: 230px !important;
    margin-left: 0px !important;
    margin-top: -15px !important;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1366px){
    svg#specilid {
        width: 230px !important;
        margin-left: -25px !important;
        margin-top: -15px !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether.

Comment: @treyBake What are you talking about? If the mediaqueries have the same specificity as the default CSS and are in front of the default CSS, the mediaqueries will get overriden

Comment: @DarkBee my point .. xD that's the evidence that you can have media queries before other CSS. That is my baseline point. Forget the change of specificity. Hence my issue with saying you *have* to have your media queries after you main stylings

Comment: either way, comments are getting far too long - removing :) (my comments rm)